# How to do pairwise column regression of a big matrix in R?

Tags: r, regression

I have a big `A = M x N` matrix and I want to regress each column (except last) with the last column. I want the result to be a dataframe with following columns

1. First column has the col names of A (except last)
2. Slope of linear regression
3. Adjusted r-squared
4. Number of non-na points in regression (this is meant to capture that for any given regression pair, I only want to include points for which both columns exist, basically exclude nulls, which I think the lm function does automatically already)

Whats the best way to do this in terms of elegance (not having to write a loop to go through columns, but using existing functions) and performance (doesnt take forever)?

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following:

```
A <- iris[1:4]
res <- apply(A[ , 1:(ncol(A)-1)], 2, function(x) lm(A[ , ncol(A)] ~ x, data = A))
slope <- sapply(res, coef)
r_squared <- sapply(res, summary)[8, , drop = FALSE]
t(rbind(slope, r_squared))
##              (Intercept) x          r.squared
## Sepal.Length -3.200215   0.7529176  0.6690277
## Sepal.Width  3.156872    -0.6402766 0.1340482
## Petal.Length -0.3630755  0.4157554  0.9271098
```